# Shiny - render selectisize from file input names

Tags: render, shiny

Within my sidebar panel of my ui.R I have:

```
        selectizeInput(
        'dv', 'DV:', choices = names(data)
    ),
```

I have a file input box that I want to read the users .csv file and extract the column names from. The data the user uploads is read correctly (I have it displayed as a data table) and saved as "data".

The selectize box remains empty however. I know I need to somehow save "data" in a way that saves it so that the ui can read it, I just cannot figure out how to do that. Here is the code I have to read the file and display the table that works perfectly, but can someone explain how to save this so I can call names(data) in my ui selectisize?

```
output$subjects <- renderDataTable({

    inFile <- input$file1

    if (is.null(inFile))
        return(NULL)

    data <- read.csv(inFile$datapath)})
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: you might need to use renderUI server-side and include your names(data) in a reactive function. Then on the UI side, outputUI from server should do the trick.